# How can I play raw audio/video tracks extracted from mp4?

Tags: video, audio, media, extract, mp4

I used `mp4creator -extract` to get the raw audio and video tracks from an mp4 file. What players can I use to play the raw tracks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VLC](http://videolan.org) will play most raw video and audio formats.

Comment: It worked for the audio track, but not for the video...

Comment: What type of video is the video track?

Comment: H264 Baseline@2.1, 150.250 secs, 482 kbps, 480x270 @ 29.970050 fps

Comment: Hmm.. I use VLC to play raw H.264 video all the time.  Check the messages window for any clues why its not working.  Perhaps you are missing the SPS and/or PPS headers.

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine LaFayette VLC often has to rely on heuristics to guess the type of raw codec in the file. Having a different file extension could completely change whether or not VLC can play the file. I suggest .h264 for your case.

Answer (score 1):

From [moitah.net](http://moitah.net), under description for its FLV Extract:

> H.264 elementary streams are not widely supported by players, but you can use [DGAVCDec](http://neuron2.net/dgavcdec/dgavcdec.html) to load them with [AviSynth](http://avisynth.org/) for editing.

Comment: ...for editing **or** just to play